# SonicWall traffic analysis

Tags: bandwidth, traffic, sonicwall, traffic-management

I have [Sonic Wall PRO 2040 Standard](http://www.sonicwall.com/us/products/PRO_2040.html) in domain network. I need to see which pc has high bandwidth usage at the moment, for example streaming music or anti-virus trying to download update, to resolve bandwidth issue.

I found in administration interface 2 useful views for bandwidth usage:

1. Log > Reports > Report View: Bandwidth Usage by IP Address
2. System > Diagnostics > Diagnostic Tool: Active Connections Monitor

But it's still not clear how is using extra bandwidth.

Question:
Is there any way or (free) tool to parse this data to get graphic chart report by PC usage in domain in certain time frame? 
Or, it doesn't have to be chart, list of top bandwidth users would be fine too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a free tool to parse the data (well new data); have you considered having a computer run [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/) to collect the bandwidth use information? At my workplace we have a Pro 2040 with it's port mirrored to a monitoring computer to do just that. Additionally if you have something like [cacti](http://www.cacti.net) that will get information from your switches you can figure out who is using the bandwidth when.

It should be noted that the first view (Log > Reports > etc.) is from the last time the SonicWall has been restarted. The second view (System > Diagnostics) is good for seeing who is making a lot of connections or happens to have a very large download in progress.